# How to calculate grant total when i change qty in datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf

I had a `DataGrid` which contains columns quantity price and total.

When I add one product it will have a price fetched from db say Rs.100
I give quantity as 5 so total will be 500.

When I add other product having price Rs.150 and I give quantity as 4 total will be 600.

These all things happening in `GridView` and the grant total(textbox outside) will be calculating sum of total(gridview total) ie `500+600=1100`

I need that 1100 or whatever when I change the quantity in the `DataGridView` itself..

Here am not using `DataGrid` template column for quantity am using only `DataGridTextBox` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st** possible solution: you can trigger the re-calculation method when the content of the cell has changed, that would be something like that:

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="yourGrid" CurrentCellChanged="yourGrid_CurrentCellChanged" ...>
```

And your **code behind** file implements:

```
 private void yourGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculate_grand_total(); // of course you have to replace that with your appropriate method name
    }
```

**2nd** possible solution: I don't know anything about your data source binding details since your question does not contain information about that - but your choose a ObservableCollection as data source, in this example a collection of JTestStep objects

```
tSteps = new ObservableCollection<JTestStep>();
```

then you can trigger actions upon a change of the collection:

```
tSteps.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_CollectionChanged);
```

and do your recalculation in that case:

```
 private void DataGrid_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        calculate_grand_total();
    }
```